# Cannot drop column MSSQL (after Hibernate?)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I created column for tests. Now I want to delete it. Hibernate `hbm2ddl.auto = validate`.

But after some tests I cant drop column.

#### Cmd:

```
alter table [x].[dbo].[tb_monitor] drop column period;
```

#### Answer:

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object 'DF__tb_monito__perio__6754599E' is dependent on column 'period'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN period failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

This column isn't FK. Did Hibernate created some dependency inside table?

Comment: it depends on your hibernate mappings; may you post the hibernate mappings as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE [x].[dbo].[tb_monitor]
DROP CONSTRAINT DF__tb_monito__perio__6754599E

alter table [x].[dbo].[tb_monitor] drop column period;
```

Answer (score 2):

`DF__tb_monito__perio__6754599E` sounds like a `default-constraint` to me

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned `validate` won't drop columns, you have to use `create` or `create-drop` instead. Beware that this will drop and recreate whole database.